# So... how about them hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

'Tis the season! [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) is back on participating Stack Exchange sites in full effect, from **16 December 2013** until **3 January 2014**.

For those of us young 'uns who weren't around last year, Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

So, it's time to decide if we want hats on our Travel-SE! **Vote** on the answers below **until 1 December 2013**. We'll enable hats only if there's sufficient support for it (for some yet undetermined value of "sufficient"). Please don't downvote an option, rather upvote only the one you choose. Of course, comment as necessary.

**EDIT**
By popular demand, hats will be enabled on Travel-SE during the aforementioned period. Final tally as of 1 Dec 2013, 10:54 UTC was 16:4 upvotes on each alternative.

Your mod friends at Travel-SE remind you to enjoy hats responsibly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**YES**, I want hats on Travel-SE!

Comment: I love these hats, can we request more hats to be added? I have a suggestion but don't know where to share.

Comment: @HaLaBi: MSO would be the place for that. There's probably already a post about it.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, leave the hats in the storage locker this year.